# How to set values of views from external file in android

Tags: android, view

Hi 
   My question is "Is it possible that I pick up all values from external file that is present in phone memory and put these values in my textviews,Buttons etc.  ?"
if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Read in the file using standard Java file I/O.

Step #2: Parse the data.

Step #3: Call appropriate setters on your widgets, such as `setText()` to change the caption of a `TextView`, `Button`, etc.